# TypeScript: What's the "right" `target` for node 11?

Tags: node.js, typescript

TypeScript's has a `target` configuration with many values, like `esnext`, `es2015`, `es6` etc. (very confusing)

NodeJs current version (11.11.0) supports many of the new features of JavaScript. Is it ok to target `esnext` on TypeScript? will it work?

If not, what's the right `target` to use when targeting nodeJs 11.11.0

Edit:

Thanks to @Seblor we know that `esnext` is very dynamic and TC39 can add features as they see fit. It represents the next version of JavaScript that is being worked on (Regarding agreeing on features)

**The refined question should be:** According to the current version of NodeJs (11.11.0) and the current version of TypeScript (3.3) can we use `esnext` as the `target`?

Comment: es2015 and es6 are the same. esnext is the next version at the time of writing. More details here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript

Comment: Looks like `esnext` is very dynamic and can always change, but `TypeScript` support for `esnext` is static (Per version)

Comment: esnext will "change" after a new version of ECMAScript is released.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so the answer is (As usual) **Depends**!
It depends on the features that you plan on using. The TypeScript version, `target` on the `tsconfig.json` and the NodeJS version.

There are two things to check before you can use a JavaScript feature:

1. You have to look at [this table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/), and look at your target environment column, in my case it's [NodeJs column](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/#node11_0). And make sure that the cell is Green. Red means that you can't run this feature on this environment.
2. Make sure that you can compile your code using TypeScript. If you can compile the code using TypeScript, you're ok. Note that you can NOT count on the [TypeScript column](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/#typescript3_2corejs3). Red cell means that the compiled code will not run on previous version of JavaScript...

For example `BigInt`:

TypeScript with `target: "esnext"` will compile (With no problem) a code with `bigint` (While the support cell is Red), and you can run a JavaScript code with bigint on `NodeJS 11`

Note that on the top left, there's the `ECMAScript` version-group. you can go lower than `esnext`

Answer (score 10):

Based on [Node-Target Mapping](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Node-Target-Mapping) on the TypeScript wiki `"es2018"` is the right mapping for Node 10, `"es2019"` is the right mapping for Node 12. It seems that non-LTS versions of Node aren't documented, but given this information I feel like `"es2018"` is the safest target.

Comment: Great to have that info on the TypeScript wiki. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Looking at [node.green](https://node.green/#ES2018), ES2018 support seems to be full in Node 11.11.0, so you should be able to set ES2018 as target with no trouble.

You can push your luck by using [ES2019](https://node.green/#ES2019) or even [ESNext](https://node.green/#ESNEXT) since the support looks good enough. However, I do not know if typescript will use non-yet-implemented features if you use ESNext as target (like the private properties).

Personally I would stick with ES2018, as I see no need to push for ESNext.

Comment: @RTW I was actually looking at Stage 3 which was (at that time : https://web.archive.org/web/20190318210754/https://node.green/) mostly covered. There is no real point to use Stage 2 (or lower) since they are likely subject to changes